# Make method and control accessible to other class

Tags: c#, winforms, static, treeview

I have my `Form1` and my `Form2`.
My `Form1` has a method which access a method that adds nodes to it's `TreeView` :

```
private void AddNode(TreeNode node)
{
  treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

I want to access this method from my `Form2` but i'm kind of stuck at the fact that

- A static AddNode method will require a static treeView1 which is kind of a bad practice.
- A new instance of `Form2` inside `Form1` will create a different instance of `treeView1` which is not what I want.

Also the `treeView1` is declared inside the designer so I can't really change it's modifier to static ( I've been told it's not a good idea to put static controls inside your form).

Any Idea how I can do this ?

Comment: Why don't you simply declare AddNode as public (non static) and you pass a reference of Form1 to Form2? For example using a public property of type Form1.

Comment: Form1 is a main form? Do you start Form2 from Form1?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky no they are both created from two other forms. I tought of passing treeview as a parameters too the form2 constructor but it's not visible at that time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best option is creating event in Form2 and subscribe to that event in Form1. When you do something on Form2 (e.g. user clicks button) raise that event (also you can pass some parameters as event argument).

Form1:

```
private void StartForm2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.SomethingHappened += Form2_SomethingHappened;
    form2.Show();
}

private Form2_SomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = (Form2)sender;
    string data = form2.Data;
    // create node
    AddNode(node);
}
```

Form2:

```
public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

public string Data
{
   get { return textBoxData.Text; }
}

private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SomethingHappened != null)
        SomethingHappened(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

*Update* thus you saying, that forms created from two other different forms, then you need some other way to subscribe to `Form2` event. You can get form2 from application opened forms collection. **OR** you can share some common object between forms:

```
public class Model
{
    public event Action<string> DataAdded; // subscribe to this event in form1

    public void AddData(string data) // call this method in form2
    {
        if (DataAdded != null)
            DataAdded(data);
    }
}
```

Well, in best world, I'd created a model, which will have all data, and just reflected that model state on `Form1`.

Comment: I find `EventHandler` to be a particularly poor type for an event.  I much prefer `Action<T>` where `T` is whatever information you want to pass from `Form2` to `Form1` is (or use the non-generic if nothing is needed).  You usually shouldn't need to pass a reference to yourself as the "sender" when doing that, and if you do, you can at least have it be strongly typed if you use `Action` instead of `EventHandler`.  I'm not even sure why `EventHandler` has survived as long as it has.  Other than that, great answer.

Comment: @Servy why not passing `EventArgs<T>`? Also I think event handler survived because of `sender` parameter. And yes, I find extremely odd second `EventArgs` parameter in non-generic `EventHandler`. But that's how all WinForms implemented.

Comment: You *can*, but it's more code, more work, `sender` is still a useless parameter, it's less clear, etc.  Why wrap all of the arguments into an `EventArgs` class when you could just pass them all as 1, 2, or 3 different arguments.  If you need to pass more than 3 things something is wrong, and perhaps you should just be passing a (strongly typed) reference to `sender`.  In this case, you can see event args is always empty.  Why bother passing it along if it's never used?  It's code bloat that adds extra overhead to new readers of the code.

Comment: As I've said with respect to `sender`, usually isn't not needed if you actually pass along the relevant info as the argument, and no passing it along (when it's not needed) reduces complexity, coupling, and tends to allow existing methods to be appropriate handlers and not need to be wrapped in something else.  If you *do* need `sender`, you can always make it the actual type of the sender via `Action<T>` instead of `object`, preventing the need for event handlers to cast.

Comment: @Servy as you can see from sample above, `sender` parameter is used :) Also consistency of code is very important. Having mix of actions and eventhandlers - thats what adds overhead. We can't change default WinForms events implementations, so I prefer to follow MS recommendations just for consistency

Comment: I'm saying, in this case, you *shouldn't* be using sender, you should use `Action<string>` and pass `Data` as the parameter to the event handler so that the caller doesn't *need* to use `sender`.  If you *did* want to use it, then I would use `Action<Form2, string>` and pass a strongly typed parameter of `sender` along with the data itself (not wrapped in an unhelpful `EventArgs` object).  Just because you can't fix *some* of your code doesn't justify not improving others, at least in this case.  I don't see any inherent advantage in the consistency [here].

Comment: Note that if you pass the relevant information in the event handler arguments you can potentially even avoid exposing `Data` publicly in the first place, and anytime you can reduce the scope of data you expose while still making it accessible everywhere it's needed is a win.

Comment: @Servy event is declared on Control, thus I follow MS recomendations for such events

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Events are not specific to controls.  Some are, but I don't see how that affects this question.  The new custom event we're creating isn't specific to `Control`, it's specific to `Form2`.

Comment: @Servy in my WinForms projects I usually have `EventArgs<T>` class, which has `T Value` property. As you can understand, it allows my stay consistent and pass any data.

Comment: You're free to do what you want, I'm just saying that there is a substantial amount of value to be gained from violating consistency, and very little to gain from maintaining it, in this particular case, because the event model of winform was simply poorly constructed to begin with.  I wanted to show you what I feel is a superior way of creating events, and I've done that.  Whether you choose to use it is none of my business.

Comment: I didn't use your method I used Controls.Find() to get my treeView reference inside the method set to static. This way he sees and instance. But if I had to make the perfect solution i'd use your process. Thanks a  lot

Answer (score 1):

Below are some options that require a reference to be stored somewhere. This may not be the best option for the situation (or it may be depending on your situation) but there are other alternatives posted too so take your pick.

---

**One solution** is you can just have a static reference to the Form1 instance that you want to use.

```
static Form1 OpenForm1 = new Form1();

//in some other code
OpenForm1.MyFunction();
```

There are many other ways, the main point is your need to ensure your Form2 instance has a reference to your Form1 instance somehow.

---

**Another option**, you can pass the instance when you create Form2:

as a property for example...

```
//create Form2 from some where else
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ReferenceToForm1 = form1;

//in form2
public Form1 ReferenceToForm1 {get;set;}

//when needed in form2
ReferenceToForm1.MyFunction();
```

Comment: For your solution 1, creating the static instance of Form1 will create a different instance of my TreeView too right ? So if I access OpenForm1 from Form2 it wont be the same treeview that Form1 has.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: It will be the same instance as long as you use the same instance of form1. Instead of using `new Form1()` exactly like above, you need to assign the actual instance of form1 (wherever you create that) as the value of `OpenForm1`.

Comment: `There are many other ways, the main point is your need to ensure your Form2 instance has a reference to your Form1 instance somehow.` No you don't, and you really shouldn't.  It greatly increases coupling between the two forms.  Using events you can ensure the child form never needs to know anything about it's parent.

Comment: @musefan I understand that I just dont understand how I can assign it to my current form. I can't do something like `static Form1 OpenForm1 = this`

Comment: @Servy: That sounds like a different question. The "many other ways" can also be applied to many other ways to reach the end goal of the user. But the question is "how to access a function". You cant access the function is you don't know where the class is

Comment: @musefan No, it doesn't sound like a different question in the least.  Just look at the highest voted answer which is a superior solution to this particular problem.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: 'OpenForm1 = this;' might actually work if you do it form within your form1 instance - give it a go. But I was thinking you should assign it at the point where you actually create Form1 to start with... perhaps from inside your 'void Main' function?

Comment: @Servy: Debatably. I don't deny it is a good solution a particular problem. And something I would use in the the right situation. But it definitely doesn't answer the question of "how can I access a function inside an instance of another form?" - it's more an answer to "what other options do I have for communicating between instance of two forms?". Anyway, I try not to assume to much about that the OP wants unless they specifically ask. My way is perfectly valid in some cases. Perhaps a case where I want to ensure only a single instance of a form is ever open, and a parent form needs to know

Comment: @musefan Technically, inside of the event is a delegate that contains a reference to the other form along with the event handler to be called, so it is accessing the method of `Form1` from `Form2`, it just does it in a sufficiently generic way that you aren't limited to that exact method call, and that relationship (which at the lowest level ends up being the exact same) is simply defined in `Form1` instead of `Form2`.  So in addition to being the better way of solving the problem, it's still technically answering the question as asked as well.

Comment: As to static form references, it's frequently abused, and occasions where it's appropriate are rare if they even exist.  It is almost never appropriate, from a design perspective, to limit a form to one instance, ever, and even if it is, it usually shouldn't be exposed publicly.  The pattern is a crutch used to avoid determining and implementing the actual relationship between the forms in question that ends up being relied on way too often.

Comment: As to your edit, I find that the approaches you've listed should either never be used, or should very, very rarely be used, whereas an event based model is almost always the appropriate method of passing information from a child form to a parent form.  Additionally, these two methods you've shown are abused so frequently that propagating them has a net harmful effect, even if the OP might find one or two cases in their career in which they're appropriate.

Comment: @Servy: Perhaps this will be one of the two times in the OP's career where they are appropriate. Maybe appropriate because it is exactly what they need, maybe appropriate because trying it will highlight different problems and learning opportunities, or maybe appropriate because they will learn something that *will* be exactly what they need later in their career. You shouldn't force your own experiences onto others. In my opinion, the best programmers are the ones that are able to make mistakes. If you just do everything the way you are told, then you are just a shallow clone of somebody else

Comment: @musefan That's all generally true, which is why I wouldn't be worried about this when dealing with a very skilled programmer. The problem is that most people in our profession don't actually do that; they take the first pattern for solving a problem they find and apply it everywhere until they have very strong reasons not to.  If people actually took the time to understand the various techniques and choose the one they thought was best, posting something like this wouldn't be harmful.  The reality is they don't, they'll continue to do this because it seems easier at first, and that's harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an interface and pass form2 a reference to something that implements the interface.

Eg:

```
public interface INodeAddable {
   void AddNode(TreeNode node);
}

public class Form1 : INodeAddable
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        var f2 = new Form2(this);
    }

    public void AddNode(TreeNode n)
    {
       // add node to tree
    }
}

public class Form2
{
  private INodeAddable x;
  public Form2(INodeAddable x)
  {
    this.x = x;
  }

  public void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     x.AddNode(someNewNode);
  }
}
```

Comment: Form2 isn't declared inside form1

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Then where is it declared?  Is there a form that creates both `Form1` and `Form2`, does `Form2` create `Form1`, or what?

Comment: They are both separate (sorry I didnt explain that) They are both created from two different form so they don't see each other when they are declared (otherwise I would have passed a reference)

Answer (score 0):

Make the forms able to access one another.

Since you said that they are generated from different forms, one approach would be to have the common root have knowledge of their existence and make the connection from their common ancestor.

The best approach i can think of, if this kind of behavior is something you will encounter in the future is to have a basic [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) that is injected into all forms, and through that you can have messages passed from one to another without having them tightly coupled. With that you can have Form1 subscribe to an event that Form2 triggers and when that event is triggerd you would add the node.